# C#/.NET ThreadException - Error Creating Window Handle

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, error-handling

I've recently implemented some (basic) unhandled error handlers in my C# (WinForms) application. The UnhandledExceptionEventHandler works fine, but in the ThreadExceptionEventHandler I'm running into something strange.

Upon closing the application, via this.Close(), standard WinForms close button, Application.Exit(), etc. something is causing a very brief error as the application closes.

The stack trace is logged, but all it gives me is this:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Error creating window handle.
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphicsInternal()
at System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog..ctor(Exception t)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The application then proceeds to close, seemingly normally. My best guess is some form of memory leak or improperly handled task shutdown, but nothing I have been able to find on the internet so far has been of much help.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** Interestingly, the error has stopped occurring... Not sure why. However, I anticipate it may return. A more long term solution would be wonderful.

Comment: are you shutting down your threads gracefully before exiting the application?

Comment: It is a *very* common bug in a Winforms app, programmers don't understand the danger of the Controls.Clear() and Controls.Remote/At() methods well enough.  Very often used wrong, not realizing they should use Dispose() instead.  Extra fun because when the controls leak finally causes the program to crash, the exception dialog will bomb as well.

Answer (score 0):

As bansi said: If you are closing a form in your WinForm application, be sure all threads using this form are shutted down previous. The last line of the stack trace (System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback) gives the hint, the a thread tries to send a message to the form which is already closed and has no window handle anymore.